# Use a Script# library (or module) in non Script# web applications

Tags: cordova, script#

i'm a C# programmer.. more or less.. and would like to start a spare time project using Cordova for visual studio. Since this is a java-script/html/css framework i would like to code in C#, compile to java-script and use these script files in cordova.

So i found Script#.. with some promising samples (which don't work by the way)
I tried to get it on my own by creating a HTML5 Module and a simple class with a static constructor to get some code that should by executed at application start and copied the .js files into the cordova projects script folder (actually a "CodeBehind" subfolder).

So here is the C# file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Html;
using jQueryApi;

namespace CodeBehind
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        static TestClass()
        {
            jQueryObject display = jQuery.Select("#P_Display");
            display.Text("World");
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the output java-script:

```
/*! CodeBehind.js 1.0.0.0
 * 
 */

"use strict";

define('CodeBehind', ['ss', 'jquery'], function(ss, $) {
  var $global = this;

  // CodeBehind.TestClass

  function TestClass() {
  }
  var TestClass$ = {

  };


  var $exports = ss.module('CodeBehind', null,
    {
      TestClass: [ TestClass, TestClass$, null ]
    });

  (function() {
    var display = $('#P_Display');
    display.text('World');
  })();

  return $exports;
});
```

and then in index.htm file, the "root-page" of the cordova application i added:

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.9/comments/require.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/CodeBehind/ss.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/CodeBehind/CodeBehind.js"></script>

<p id="P_Display">Hello</p>

<script>
    var test = CodeBehind.TestClass();
</script>
```

and surprise.. nothing happens at all..
i think it's because of the module, is it?

what do i need to do, to get this "static-code" running? I also tried to create an object that was compiled with Script#, but the the type was not defined. Any suggestions to address this?

Thanks very much for your help!

Kai

Answer (score 0):

reading the [documentation of RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) cleared everything up..